# Name of a structured matrix

Tags: matrices

I am looking for the name of the class of matrices with the following structure.

$$X = \begin{bmatrix} A &B\\B&A \end{bmatrix}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are block matrices.

Thanks

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ scalars or matrices ?

Answer (score 0):

It is called a bi-symmetric matrix.

Comment: I'm afraid not if it denotes a block matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If it a block matrix, I met the term `block-symmetric matrix`, but it doesn't seem to be standard terminology.